# Show spin image while loading chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plot, dygraphs

I want to show a spinner (from spin.js) while loading a dygraphs plot. So far it work's, but I can't make it that the spin-image is displayed in the div where the chart is rendered. If I use another empty div container ('testdiv') for my spin - all is fine.

Here my code:

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="radiogroup" value="2012" checked="checked" />2012
<input type="radio" id="r2" name="radiogroup" value="2013" />2013

<div id="graph1" style="width:700px; height:400px;"></div>
<div id="testdiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[name=radiogroup]:radio").click(function() {
    var target = document.getElementById('testdiv');
    var spinner = new Spinner().spin(target);

    var year = $(this).val()

    var g1 = new Dygraph(
      document.getElementById("graph1"),year+".csv",
      { }
    );

    g1.ready(function () {
      spinner.stop();
    });
  });

  $("input:radio[name=radiogroup][value=2012]").click();   
});

</script>
```

So, if i change this line to the div "graph1" it stop working:

```
var target = document.getElementById('graph1');
```

See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hp4t8hap/

Comment: Can't you just put the spinner div on top of the `#graph1` div? Once you create the `Dygraph` object, `#graph1` is its div. It can do whatever it likes with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is the best idea, but I used the drawCallback function which now if it's the first call back :

`drawCallback: function(dygraph, isInitial)
{
  if(isInitial)
    $("#loading").slideUp(function()
    {
      $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("readonly");
      canLoadData = true;
      $("button").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("button > i").remove();
    });
},`